# NoneType is not callable using elasticsearch from pyes

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyes

My code is:

```
import pyes

conn = pyes.ES(myes_path)

siplist =['a','b','c']
diplist = ['d','e','f']

bf = pyes.filters.BoolFilter()
bf.add_must(pyes.filters.TermsFilter('sip',siplist))
bf.add_must(pyes.filters.TermsFilter('dip',diplist))

fq = pyes.query.FilteredQuery(pyes.query.MatchAllQuery(),bf)
res = conn.search(fq,'hhhhh')
print res.total
```

I always get this error:

> bits = error.split('[', 1) TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Does anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: bits = error.split where is this line

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example (I don't know what the myes_path is meant to represent? Is this a data file?), and maybe the stack trace for the Python error. Sounds like your error is in one of the values you're passing to pyes.

Comment: hi Rahul and Andrew, thanks for replying.  I  tried my code on other dataset just new  and it worked, but when I made the diplist a long list, I mean the len(diplist) is a big value, say 160000, it shows ' error.split('[', 1) TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable' again. Is this because the length of diplist exceeds  maximum value  set by pyes?

Comment: And, when I do the search, can I do something like res = conn.search(fq, ['hhhhh','gggg'])  where ['hhhhh','gggg'] means indices list, is this valid in pyes?

Comment: You should add the complete traceback [mcve]

Comment: I had this error when making records from keys that contained punctuation. Removing the punctuation fixed the issue.